# Perfect Scrollbar not working with accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I am trying to use the Perfect Scrollbar in collaboration with an accordion slider menu, but its not working as expected. Please [check the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/prashu421/egkfxzrt/)

The scrollbar is getting activated for the first sub-menu, and that too not being displayed on the page load, but I have to scroll in the container first to see the scroll bar.

But the new scrollbar doesn't seem to be updated for the second and third sub-menus.
I am trying to update the PerfectScrollbar function as suggested in [here](https://jqueryplugins.net/perfect-scroll-bar/) and many other places on internet using `ps.update();` Not sure if the function call is properly done here by me or not.

***Update:***
Got it work, leaving it here, as it may help somebody later.
https://jsfiddle.net/prashu421/egkfxzrt/

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // Store variables
        //var ps = new PerfectScrollbar('.sub-menu');

        const container = document.querySelector('.sub-menu');
        const ps = new PerfectScrollbar(container);

        var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),
            accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu');

        // Open the first tab on load
        accordion_head.first().addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');

        // Click function
        accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {
            // Disable header links 
            ps.update();                
            event.preventDefault();

            // Show and hide the tabs on click
            if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
                accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
                $(this).next().stop(true,true).slideToggle('normal');
                accordion_head.removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
```

Appreciate your consideration and help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only applying the perfect scrollbar to the first container element. Try using `querySelectorAll('.sub-menu')` and applying the perfect scrollbar to each container:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.sub-menu');
  document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu').forEach(container => {
    new PerfectScrollbar(container);
  });

  const accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a');
  const accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu');

  // Open the first tab on load
  accordion_head.first().addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');

  // Click function
  accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {
    // Disable header links 
    event.preventDefault();

    // Show and hide the tabs on click
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
      accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
      $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle('normal');
      accordion_head.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion,
.accordion ul,
.accordion li,
.accordion a,
.accordion span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.accordion li {
  list-style: none;
}

.accordion li>a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 110px;
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #cbcbcb;
  font: bold 12px/32px Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  background: #717377;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #717377 0%, #515356 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #717377), color-stop(100%, #515356));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #717377 0%, #515356 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #717377 0%, #515356 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #717377 0%, #515356 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #717377 0%, #515356 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#717377', endColorstr='#515356', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.accordion>li:hover>a,
.accordion>li:target>a,
.accordion>li>a.active {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  background: #4f5154;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5154 0%, #2d2e30 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4f5154), color-stop(100%, #2d2e30));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5154 0%, #2d2e30 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4f5154 0%, #2d2e30 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4f5154 0%, #2d2e30 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4f5154 0%, #2d2e30 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4f5154', endColorstr='#2d2e30', GradientType=0);
}

.accordion li>a span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0px 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font: normal bold 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #404247;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.accordion>li:hover>a span,
.accordion>li:target>a span,
.accordion>li>a.active span {
  color: #fdfdfd;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  background: #161616;
}


/* Images */

.accordion>li>a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 4px 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(Images/icone_accordeon.png);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.accordion li.files>a:before {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.accordion li.files:hover>a:before,
.accordion li.files:target>a:before,
.accordion li.files>a.active:before {
  background-position: 0px -24px;
}

.accordion li.mail>a:before {
  background-position: -24px 0px;
}

.accordion li.mail:hover>a:before,
.accordion li.mail:target>a:before,
.accordion li.mail>a.active:before {
  background-position: -24px -24px;
}

.accordion li.cloud>a:before {
  background-position: -48px 0px;
}

.accordion li.cloud:hover>a:before,
.accordion li.cloud:target>a:before,
.accordion li.cloud>a.active:before {
  background-position: -48px -24px;
}

.accordion li.sign>a:before {
  background-position: -72px 0px;
}

.accordion li.sign:hover>a:before,
.accordion li.sign:target>a:before,
.accordion li.sign>a.active:before {
  background-position: -72px -24px;
}


/* Sub Menu */

.sub-menu li a {
  color: #797979;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  background: #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.sub-menu li:hover a {
  background: #efefef;
}

.sub-menu li:last-child a {
  border: none;
}

.sub-menu li>a span {
  color: #797979;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  background: #dbdbdb;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.sub-menu em {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 14px;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  font: normal 10px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* Functionality */

.accordion li>.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.accordion li:target>.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

#bloc-accordeon {
  width: 40%;
}

#bloc-accordeon p {
  Font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #797979;
}


/*Scroll bar styling*/

.ps__rail-x,
.ps__rail-y {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/master/dist/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/master/css/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bloc-accordeon">
  <ul class="accordion">
    <li id="one" class="files">
      <a href="#one">One</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>01</em>4.2 FFF</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>02</em>6.3 FFF</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>03</em>4.0 FFF</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>04</em>4.2 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>05</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>06</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>07</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>08</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="two" class="mail">
      <a href="#two">Two</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>01</em>4.2 FFF</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>02</em>6.3 FFF</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>03</em>4.0 FFF</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>04</em>4.2 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>05</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>06</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>07</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>08</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="three" class="cloud">
      <a href="#two">Three</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>01</em>4.2 FFF</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>02</em>6.3 FFF</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>03</em>4.0 FFF</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>04</em>4.2 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>05</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>06</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>07</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="#"><em>08</em>3.0 TTD</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Gotcha, thanks so much for your help. Any idea why I am unable to see the scrollbar after the sub-menu is loaded? I have to scroll first to see it, If you observe, when I hover the sub-menu items, I am unable to see the scroller

Comment: Hmm I'm not quite sure. My guess is that it's specific to the PerfectScrollbar implementation. Try looking at the documentation. It seems like it needs to compute the height of the scrollbar first. You can see if there is an `always display` option or something to that effect.

Comment: It is actually working if its not collaborated with this menu - https://jsfiddle.net/utatti/dyvL31r6/
Will try to figure it out... Anyways thanks again mate.

Comment: here's the final updated fiddle, working as expected now. 
https://jsfiddle.net/prashu421/egkfxzrt/